# Jboss poi deploy

Tags: jboss

I am importing required classes as follows:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

My *ejb-pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

In eclipse everything works fine. Compile, run. 
But when i try to deploy ejb.jar to jboss EAP 6.3. i have error: 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row`

I think the problem : poi-ooxml-3.11.jar and poi-3.11.jar  have the same package: `org\apache\poi\ss\usermodel` but the `Row.class` in poi-3.11.jar.
I dont know how i can deploy correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try import only poi-ooxml. The dependency poi is load